# Add second IP4 to the server (CentOS)

Tags: server, dns, centos7, nameservers, cwp

I just wanted to store a second IP address in the CWP.
I used the IP Manager, which is located in the admin panel.
He creates the following file:

ifcfg-:1
with the following content

```
DEVICE=:1
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=5.199.130.204
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
GATEWAY=91.194.84.1
```

when I enter the command

```
service network restart
I get the following message
[root@cpanel network-scripts]# service network restart
Restarting network (via systemctl):
** (pkttyagent:19657): WARNING **: 18:17:04.966: Unable to register authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Cannot determine user of subject
Error registering authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Cannot determine user of subject (polkit-error-quark, 0)
[ OK ]
```

but with the command ifconfig I cannot see the new IP address

```
[root@cpanel network-scripts]# ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet 172.17.0.1 netmask 255.255.0.0 broadcast 172.17.255.255
ether 02:42:80:6b:74:bf txqueuelen 0 (Ethernet)
RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
enp1s0f0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet 91.194.84.77 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 91.194.84.255
inet6 fe80::225:90ff:fee1:a1cc prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20<link>
ether 00:25:90:e1:a1:cc txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 896454492 bytes 77246656595 (71.9 GiB)
RX errors 0 dropped 121675 overruns 21 frame 0
TX packets 328489556 bytes 321552938430 (299.4 GiB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
device memory 0xfea80000-feafffff
enp1s0f1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether 00:25:90:e1:a1:cd txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
device memory 0xfe980000-fe9fffff
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536
inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0
inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10<host>
loop txqueuelen 1000 (Local Loopback)
RX packets 28795464 bytes 8187828621 (7.6 GiB)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 28795464 bytes 8187828621 (7.6 GiB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet 192.168.122.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.122.255
ether 52:54:00:d8:74:c8 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

I would like to add the IP 5.199.130.204 to my server and then use it for the 2 nameservers.
however I cannot recognize this ip after entering it with the command ifconfig.

did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

ifconfig shows only one result

check use
`id address` or `nmcli con show conname`

can append
`nmcli con mod +ipv4.addresses ip/prefix`

or

append to ifcfg-*

`IPADDR1=ip`
`PREFIX1=prefix`  but, direct change is not recommended

Answer (score 0):

You should fix the polkitd issue that is appearing

groupadd -g 23 nohidproc
usermod -a -G nohidproc polkitd
mount -o remount,rw,hidepid=2,gid=nohidproc /proc
systemctl restart polkit
Add the following in /etc/fstab as well
echo "proc /proc proc defaults,hidepid=2,gid=nohidproc 0 0" >> /etc/fstab